# C# Read From .txt file on change update WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to C# I have a program that writes to a text file. I am trying to write some thing that can read that text file when it has changed and display the text file conext within a WPF app that I would have open.

I have the bit for the file change listener down, I know how to read the file text. I don't know how to update the text block on the WPF form with the text.

Here is the XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="ShowProgressBox.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" 
            Height="75" 
            Width="225" 
            ResizeMode="NoResize" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"
            WindowStyle="None"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="5"
            AllowsTransparency="True"

            ToolTip="Activate window and press [ESC] key to close."
            >
        <Grid Margin="0,0,-10,0" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Focusable="True" >
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Margin="54,0,50,43" Width="121" FontFamily="Lucida Sans" ><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Macro Progress"/></TextBlock>
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Desktop\code-512.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" RenderTransformOrigin="0.494,0.484"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="46,22,20,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FileText}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="159"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

The code behind looks like the following:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Security.Permissions;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Permissions;


    namespace ShowProgressBox
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public string FileText { get; set; }

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Topmost = true;
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                this.Top = 10;
                this.Left = 10;
                this.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(HandleEsc);
                RunWatch();
            }

            private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                this.DragMove();
            }

            private void HandleEsc(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
                {
                    Close();
                }
            }

            [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
            public static void RunWatch()
            {
                FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

                // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and the renaming of files or directories. 
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                // FILE TO WATCH PATH AND NAME. 
                watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\Desktop\";
                watcher.Filter = "test.ini";
                // Add event handlers.
                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
                // Begin watching.
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }

            // Define the event handlers. 
            private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {
                //THE FILE CHANGED NOW LET'S UPDATE THE TEXT.

                string Text;

                try
                {
                    //Read file update the Graphical User Interface 
                   FileText = File.ReadAllText("ShowProgress.ini");

                }
                catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    FileText = "File not found.";
                }
                catch (System.IO.FileLoadException)
                {
                    FileText = "File Failed to load";
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException)
                {
                    FileText = "File I/O Error";
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    FileText = err.Message;
                }
            }

            private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
            {
                // There will be code here to re-create file if it is renamed
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I miss the question?!

Comment: Also, that is a *ton* of code. Not quite an MVCE (also not using MVVM :( )

Comment: How do I read the text from the file and update the TextBlock with the text from the file. I know that there is some kind of binding that would do that but this is literally the 2nd app that I have ever made. I am all self taught and my company will not pay for training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief, all you are missing is a raising a PropertyChanged event. This is how the binding target acknowledge the GUI that it's time for updating the screen.

But, a bit more than that is the bugs you are having using FileSystemWatcher (i.e. You are watching test.ini but you are reading file text in ShowProgress.ini and the file path is missing) and the fact that you should try to learn WPF in a MVVM way. So, try out the code that I do for you.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly string pathToWatch;
    private const string FileToWatch = "test.ini";

    private string fileText;
    public string FileText
    {
        get { return fileText; }
        set
        {
            if (fileText == value) return;
            fileText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        pathToWatch = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile") + @"\DeskTop\";

        RunWatch();
    }

    public void RunWatch()
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and the renaming of files or directories. 
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // FILE TO WATCH PATH AND NAME. 
        watcher.Path = pathToWatch;
        watcher.Filter = FileToWatch;
        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.Created += OnChanged;
        watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
        watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //THE FILE CHANGED NOW LET'S UPDATE THE TEXT.

        try
        {
            //Read file update the Graphical User Interface 
            FileText = File.ReadAllText(pathToWatch + FileToWatch);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            FileText = "File not found.";
        }
        catch (FileLoadException)
        {
            FileText = "File Failed to load";
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            FileText = "File I/O Error";
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            FileText = err.Message;
        }
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // There will be code here to re-create file if it is renamed
    }

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reference that needs to be used here to access the ViewModelBase class? I thought that it was the Microsoft.TeamFoundation but am unable to find it.

Comment: No external references is required but the targeted .net framework is 4.5 for "CallerMemberName" to work ... If u r using earlier version net framework, u can remove the CallerMemberName attribute and make the corresponding change in the view model property